# Cannot deploy rails 5 application through capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, gitlab, capistrano, ssh-keys

Last time I tried deploy app with capistrano, I had the error:

```
git exit status: 128 (SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError)
git stdout: GitLab: The project you were looking for could not be found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

From logs, I see that Sshkit stoped on this command:

```
DEBUG [ad9c3769] Command: ( export HOST="host.ru" GIT_ASKPASS="/bin/echo" GIT_SSH="/tmp/git-ssh-project-production-user.sh" ; /usr/bin/env git ls-remote git@gitlab.com:team/host/project.git HEAD )
 DEBUG [22255d19]   GitLab: The project you were looking for could not be found.
 DEBUG [22255d19]
 DEBUG [22255d19]   fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
 DEBUG [22255d19]
 DEBUG [22255d19]
 DEBUG [22255d19]   Please make sure you have the correct access rights
 DEBUG [22255d19]
 DEBUG [22255d19]   and the repository exists.
```

Basically, my capistrano production deploy had working and configured correctly, but this moment sshkit used by capistrano cannot reach the private repository on gitlab.com.  Also, connection to repo configured on a server with gitlab deploy keys. Seems like something changed in gitlab api. Don't know.

However, when I login to server with ssh and try command:

```
export HOST="host.ru" GIT_ASKPASS="/bin/echo" GIT_SSH="/tmp/git-ssh-project-production-user.sh" ;
/usr/bin/env git ls-remote git@gitlab.com:team/host/project.git HEAD
```

it works fine, as expected, with the output:

```
5e46ac5b30d25499b375481f3c2377cb70f0346e    HEAD
```

Maybe someone have met this problem already and know how to solve, please help me.

Comment: I had a similar problem and figured out that the remote repo URL has changed and removing the `repo` folder on the remote host fixes the problem. Looks like Capistrano relies on repo url info from `repo` folder explicitely.

Comment: As I remember, I fixed this by fully removing all scripts in  `/tmp` folder generated by capistrano on server.

Comment: Seems, you absolutely right jedi. Also I removed all repo info, related to project.

Comment: I recently had a conversation with them about it. Seems like they have fixed it but it still doesn't work. See this Github issue https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/issues/2037 Could add your story to it? The more info they have the more they are likely to fix it.

Comment: I had appended the story with link to this issue in github issue post you've mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by fully removing all scripts in `/tmp` folder generated by capistrano and files in `repo` folder on server.
Also, as jedi said in comments, the problem was related to repo info.